# What kind of Categorical object is an RDF Model?

Tags: logic, category-theory, model-theory, quiver

[RDF1.1 semantics](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#simple-interpretations) defines an RDF Interpretation and mixes up the model and the mapping from the syntax to the model. I want to work out independently what its category of all models is. (In order to perhaps later be able to define an [institution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_model_theory) for it).

Luckily the model is extremely simple:

> 1. A non-empty set IR of resources, called the domain or universe of I.
> 2. A set IP, called the set of properties of I.
> 3. A mapping IEXT from IP into the powerset of $IR \times IR$ i.e. the set of sets of pairs $ \langle x, y \rangle$ with x and y in IR .

It looks like one can map this structure nicely to [a Quiver](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quiver), by creating the set of arrows like this $AR =\{ \langle a,p,b\rangle \mid p \in IP \land \langle a,b \rangle \in IEXT(p) \}$. We can then define two functions $s,t : AR \to IR \cup IP$ as $s \langle a,p,b \rangle=a$ and ${t \langle a,p,b \rangle =b}$ which gives us the Quiver.

This is a subset of all Quivers I believe. Is it a special one? 
By mapping this to a Quiver this way I loose the type information, which does play a central role in RDF. So I was wondering if there is a structure that keeps that, so that I could know that all arrows that are part of the same $IEXT(p)$ powerset have something in common.

Do I need to add to the set of arrows some more arrows from an element of one of the relations selected by IEXT, ie to a subobject of $IR \times IR$. So we need to add $TP= \{ \langle rels,0,a \rangle, \langle rels,1,b \rangle \mid p \in IP \land IEXT(p) = rels \land  \langle a,b \rangle \in rels \}$ ?

As this is used for logical modelling and we have powersets I was wondering if there is an obvious relation to topos theory perhaps...

Comment: The context to this question is best explained by the (failed) question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2896172/how-should-one-model-rdf-semantics-in-terms-of-category-theory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is often useful to convert set-valued mappings into bundles. You've nearly done this to $IEXT$.

I think the most natural repackaging of the data you list for a category theoretic point of view is that an "RDF-object" in a category with products consists of:

- An object $IR$
- An object $IP$
- A monomorphism $AR \hookrightarrow IR \times IP \times IR$

Then you have the fact that an RDF-object of **Set** is basically the same thing as what you define to be a model: the remaining part of the correspondence is that $IEXT$ is given by taking pullback squares:
$$ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
IEXT(p) @>>> AR
\\ @VVV @VVV
\\1 @>p>> IP
\end{CD} $$
where the arrow on the right is the suggested projection map, $1$ denotes a one-element set, and for $p \in IP$, I also write $p$ for the morphism $1 \to IP$ whose value is $p$.

The only essential difference between "RDF-object" and what you define to be a model is that you additionally require $IR \neq \varnothing$.

Incidentally, this abstract knowledge ***strongly*** suggests that you get a better behaved notion by dropping the $IR \neq \varnothing$ condition from the basic definitions — instead that condition should be viewed as an *additional property* that an RDF-object might have.

RDF-objects are models of a *finite limit sketch*. E.g. this means you can choose a category $\mathcal{T}$ and some additional data, and then an RDF-object in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a functor $\mathcal{T} \to \mathcal{C}$ satisfying certain properties.

There is an implied notion of a morphism between two RDF-objects, and the category of RDF objects and said morphisms in **Set** is a particularly nice one. For example, it is [locally finitely presentable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessible_category#locally_presentable).

---

From the point of view of categorical logic, this sketch describes the formal first-order theory described by

- There is a type $R$ whose members are called resources
- There is a type $P$ whose members are called properties
- There is a ternary relation $X$ whose arguments are of type $R$, $P$, $R$ respectively

There are no axioms for this theory; it's just the two types together with the ternary relation symbol.

Comment: Reading chapter 7 of Barr and Wells excellent "Category theory for Computing Science" on "Finite Product Sketches" http://www.math.mcgill.ca/triples/Barr-Wells-ctcs.pdf to fully understand your answer :-) Actually chapter "10.1 Finite limit sketches" is probably the one I need for this, but I have to work my way to it. http://www.math.mcgill.ca/triples/Barr-Wells-ctcs.pdf